# Deploying OpenGeo Suite App on Apache Tomcat?

Tags: boundless-suite, tomcat, apache

I am a beginner trying to develop a web app using Opengeo Suite. I've manage to test it localy on my personnal computer and I would like to deploy it to the web. It seems like Tomcat Apache is what I need to work with but I can't seem to figure how to get started.

I know it is a "wide" question but I just need to know where to start, I'm usually good at learning by myself and figuring things out but I've been reading and searching on the web for a couple of days and can't really find how to do this. I have used ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) to share my app quickly but only the layout and base layer would show up (the overlay layers are missing).

Can someone give me an idea of where to start, or the major steps I should take in order to make my app available on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say start by reading through the documentation for OpenGeo Suite. It has good guides that should walk you through everything from installation to building and deploying an application.

http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/